# could not resolve all dependencies for configuration X could not find Z required by B > A

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, groovy, gradle

I've already **solved** this but i'm still curious as to why gradle behaves this way.

In my gradle project i have 2 gradle projects, one named app that is configured with the `ear` plugin and one named core that is deployed in the lib folder of the ear

I was getting the following error when trying to build my gradle project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:earlib'.
> Could not find org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5.
  Required by:
      saturn:app:unspecified > saturn:core:unspecified
> Could not find commons-io:commons-io:2.4.
  Required by:
      saturn:app:unspecified > saturn:core:unspecified
> Could not find org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5.
  Required by:
      saturn:app:unspecified > saturn:core:unspecified
> Could not find log4j:log4j:1.2.17.
  Required by:
      saturn:app:unspecified > saturn:core:unspecified
```

My app build.gradle file is:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

dependencies {
    earlib project(":core")
}
```

and my core build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.5'
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.5'
    runtime 'log4j:log4j:1.2.17'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}
```

### Temporary Solution:

I was able to resolve the issue by adding the mavenCentral repository to my app build.gradle like so:

```
apply plugin: 'ear'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    earlib project(':core')
}
```

**HOWEVER** I'm still curious as to why the depending project needs to know what repository the core project resolves it's dependencies from. this [document on dependency management](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/dependency_management.html) doesn't seem to have a very good explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When resolving a configuration, Gradle (only) uses the repositories declared in the same project as the configuration. Hence when resolving the ear project's `earlib` configuration, only the ear project's repositories are taken into account. That's one reason why it's common to declare all repositories under `subprojects` in the root build script.

Comment: Thanks! I'll add that configuration to my build now :)